# Method `andReturn` not recognized in OCMStub

Tags: ios, ocmock, xcode6.3

I want to do unit testing with XCTest, using mocks. I downloaded OCMock 3.1.2 from ocmock.org. I try the new syntax, as explained here: http://ocmock.org/reference/#stubing-methods

However, Xcode 6.3 does not recognize the method `andReturn`, see screenshot. The only method it recognizes is `andForwardToRealObject`. When I command-click on this method, it opens the file `OCMStubRecorder.h`, in which in the interface `andReturn` *is* defined! Why does Xcode not recognize it?

[image: Screenshot Xcode not recognizing andReturn]

If I type it anyway, it is sometimes recognized by the compiler, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but at least for me I can't use `andReturn`via dot notation for some reason. If you were to do `[OCMStub([mock_db_helper getArticleForArticleId:1]) andReturn:<mock data>];` does that work?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to a collision with [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla) explained in [this Nocilla issue](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla/issues/81). You can remap `OCMock`'s `andReturn` macro to `OCAndReturn` like this in your prefix header:

```
#define OCandReturn(aValue) _andReturn(({ __typeof__(aValue) _val = (aValue); NSValue *_nsval = [NSValue value:&_val withObjCType:@encode(__typeof__(_val))]; if(OCMIsObjectType(@encode(__typeof(_val)))) { objc_setAssociatedObject(_nsval, "OCMAssociatedBoxedValue", *(__unsafe_unretained id *) (void *) &_val, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN); } _nsval; }))
```

Your code would then become:

```
OCMStub([mock_db_helper getArticleForArticleId:1]).OCAndReturn(...);
```

This unfortunately necessitates the need to update it if `OCMock`'s macro changes but will avoid the symbol duplication problem.